# Strong params: No mass assignment error message when parameter not on whitelist is passed onto database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I've newly upgraded to rails 4.0.1

Simple enough experiment to test the new strong params:

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_status, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /statuses
  # yersh GET /statuses.json
  def index
    @statuses = Status.all
  end

  # GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json
  def show
    # GET thingy
  end


  # GET /statuses/sdfnew
  def new
    @status = Status.new
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @status = Status.new(status_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /statuses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /statuses/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update(status_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /statuses/1
  # DELETE /statuses/1.json
  def destroy
    @status.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_status
      @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def status_params
      params.require(:status).permit(:nothing)
    end
```

As you can see, the only parameter I have whitelisted is something called 'nothing'. So here's my new status view and form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@status, html: { class: "form-group"}) do |f| %>
  <% if @status.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@status.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this status from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @status.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :content, class: "form-control" %><br>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, it has one input, for a parameter called content. I enter data and submit the form, and I am routed to  get a flash saying 'Status was successfully created.', and routed to the status. Now, the content field is empty on this status (note the second column from the left):

```
24||2013-11-29 16:34:01.389499|2013-11-29 16:34:01.389499|
```

So this means the status_params method did do its job of stopping 'content' from being written to the database, but the damn thing is still created, albeit with an empty 'content' entry. I want a mass-assignment error, like in the good old days of attr_accessor. How can I get this behavior? I wish to stop a status being created if one of its attributes is not white listed?

Also, just venting here, but does anyone else think this whitelist strong params thing is utterly, utterly, utterly vile? Loved attr_access to bits, it was well organised (models contained everything to do with models, like they should), it was easy and not fiddly, and you could glance at your model files to see what attributes they have. No, when I want to verify what attributes a model has I need to fire up my rails console and run

```
Status.column_names
```

Urgh it's all just so hideous. Is there a chance it could be changed back? For nutjobs who want to have their model behavior in their controllers there should be gem for this. To overhaul rails like this, and not add backward functionality add the very least, is just rude.

**This question is still open! I understand this behaviour does not happen in production, so that's great, but I'd still like to get a mass-assignment error for debugging purposes in the development environment, as well as the console message!**

Comment: what is your rails version? if you wan to use `attr_accessible`, you should take a look this gem [protected_attribute](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes)

Comment: I do know of protected_attribute, but if this is the direction Rails is moving I don't want to fight it. Really hope they bring back attr_accessible though. Rails 4.0.1

Comment: In my experience it logs illegal params in development and throws forbidden attribute errors in production. I greatly prefer strong parameters to attr_accessible but then again I may be a nutjob for liking the easier fine grain control.

Comment: Haha, maybe! Okay, that sounds like the problem never existed in the first place, thanks for sorting that out. I wish I could still get a mass assignment error in development though, for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/strong_parameters/railtie.rb) you can configure this behavior:

```
initializer "strong_parameters.config", :before => "action_controller.set_configs" do |app|
  ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = app.config.action_controller.delete(:action_on_unpermitted_parameters) do
    (Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?) ? :log : false
  end
end
```

Try setting in config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = false
```

I haven't tried it but there definitely should be some way.